# Web server / application unable to read providerName "System.Data.SqlClient"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am planning to use identity framework for the authentication in my ASP.NET MVC 5 web application.

Actually it worked as expected in my local/dev machine. I deployed the code to a web server, but when I run the application, I get an error that the web server not able to read the `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` from the config file.

But it worked perfectly fine in my local machine.

[image]

Comment: take a close look at the image, "providerName="System.DataSqlClient", is what I see.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have connect that library locally only.

One way is to upload on bin the dlls that connected with SqlClient, but its better to go to your project, right click on the project, open the "Manage NuGet Package..."

and include the "System.Data.SqlClient" package.

Then compile and upload again the result to your server.

[image]